# Keeping node ids of a OSM data even after converting it into GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, geojson

I have an OSM data, I need to convert it into GeoJSON and edit it then again need to convert it back into OSM format. but I losing the nodeIds. Do we have any method in GeoJSON to keep the ids?

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the established editors to edit OSM data directly? What is the purpose of editing GeoJSON instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stick my neck out and say no, in the general case we haven't.

GeoJSON simply does not have the same structure as OSM data, and any attempt at conveying it, e.g, by using the `properties` field to store something, is going to be horribly brittle.

In specific cases, such as for edits that do not affect geometry, it *might* be possible to come up with something, but I would not bet on it.

(Obviously, if you are prepared to write your own processing pipeline, anything can be done, but in that case you might as well skip GeoJSON and work on OSM data directly!)